# Достоинства и недостатки перемещения CSS в HTML?

Tags: html, css, оптимизация-сайтов

На сколько я понимаю, если перенести CSS-код в тег style в header я с одной стороны приобрету в скорости загрузки, но потеряю в скорости повторной загрузки, т.е. веб-страница не кешируется и заново будет загружаться с этим CSS-кодом каждый раз?

Так ли это и есть ли иные достоинства, недостатки у этих вариантов?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Внешние таблицы стилей**

*Преимущества:*

- Может контролировать стили нескольких документов одновременно.
- Классы могут быть созданы для использования в многих типах HTML элементов нескольких документов.
- Селекторы и группирование могут быть применены к стилям в сложных контекстах.

*Недостатки:*

- Необходимо для каждого документа подгружать отдельно внешнюю таблицу стилей.
- Отрисовка документа может быть приостановлена, пока не загрузятся внешние стили.
- Становится громоздким, если объявлено небольшое количество стилей.

**Встроенная таблица стилей**

*Преимущества:*

- Созданные классы могут использоваться многими тегами документа.
- Селекторы и группирование могут быть применены к стилям в сложных контекстах.
- Не требуется дополнительных загрузок для получения информации о стилях.

*Недостатки:*

- Этот метод не может контролировать стили многих документов одновременно.

**Встроенные(inline) стили**

*Преимущества:*

- Полезны для маленького количества стилей.
- Могут перезаписывать правила, наложенные другими стилями.

*Недостатки:*

- Не отделяют вид от содержания (главную цель SGML/HTML).
- Не могут контролировать стили нескольких документов одновременно.
- Селекторы и    группирование не могут быть применены к стилям в сложных контекстах.

Comment: `Отрисовка документа может быть приостановлена, пока не загрузятся внешние стили.` - так а разве отрисовка не приостановится в случае с встроенной таблицей стилей? Так же браузер будет ждать её, только меньше выходит...

Answer (score 2):

На мой взгляд, нет ни одного плюса размещения css внутри html.

Если говорить о скорости, да, быстрее будет, если сервер вернет один файл вместо двух, но именно при двух файлах, как мне кажется, прирост скорости должен быть невероятно малым значением, а если файлов 100+, тогда в бой идут плагины для минификации css, js, спрайты и т.д.

Недостатоков размещения css в html вижу массу:

- Менее читаемый код в html
- Мешанина в html из данных и их способа отображения
- Дублирование кода при использовании одних и тех же стилей на разных
  страницах
- Сложная поддержка кода

Для меня это как пхп код с выборкой из базы данных внутри html страниц.